# How can you ensure that SizeChangedEventHandler runs LATER than a PropertyChanged result?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `SizeChangedEventHandler` that sets the position of my window each time the width of the window changes. (If the window becomes 100 wide, its `Left` property gets set to 100 away from the right edge of the screen, so the window is always aligned with the right edge of the screen.)

What makes the width change is a button's "Visibility" being toggled between "Visible" and "Collapsed", using a `Binding` to a bool in my code-behind and a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` (all demonstrated below).

The problem is, it appears that the position is being calculated based on the width *before* the button disappears, instead of *after*. This makes the window not line up with the right edge of the screen as desired. It sits 100 away when the width is 80, and 80 away when the width is 100.

```xml
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->

<Window
    x:Class="blah.MainWindow"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Topmost="True"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ...
>
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Margin="3,0,3,3">
            // IF is my shortened name for BooleanToVisibilityConverter
            // In an <Application.Resources> I have <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IF" />
            <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding showThing, Converter={StaticResource IF}}">
                <Button />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button />
            <Button />
            <Button />
            <Button Click="handleClick" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then its code-behind

```cs
// MainWindow.xaml.cs

namespace blah
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _showThing = false;
        public bool showThing
        {
            get { return _showThing; }
            set { _showThing = value; this.OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.setPosition_EventHandler);
            this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(this.setPosition_EventHandler);
        }

        private void setPosition_EventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rect desktopWorkingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
            this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
        }

        private void handleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            showThing = !showThing;
        }
    }
}
```

## Additional attempt

`showThing` gets correctly set when the right button is clicked, the left button is correctly being collapsed and then visible, `setPosition_EventHandler` is getting called each time so the window repositions. It's just that it repositions as if the button is the opposite visibility from what it should be.

I tried adding a `setPosition` that does the same as `setPosition_EventHandler`, and calling it in the setter for `showThing` as such:

```cs
set { _showThing = value; this.OnPropertyChanged(); setPosition(); }
```

but it still seems to happen before the property change causes the button's visibility to switch and thus the window width to change.

Does anyone know how I can make sure the size change event handler actually happens *after* the width has changed due to the button being collapsed?

Comment: `The problem is, it appears that the position is being calculated based on the width before the button disappears, instead of after.` can you explain what you mean by `before the button disappears`, the code above isn't doing anything with a button. Also have you tried setting the binding to the visibility of the button to the same as the stack panel?

Comment: Ya, for sure. See the `StackPanel` with `Visibility="..."`. It has a `Button` inside it, which is what takes up the space. To be technically accurate, I could have said "the StackPanel disappears".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The issue is, binding happens actually later than windows messages happen because of the dispatcher. In short, messages dealing with the UI will happen before binding happens; you have no control over this. You'd have to do some quirky adding/removing handlers etc..

Comment: Ah, interesting, thanks. So is there a more appropriate place to run `setPosition`, instead of as a `SizeChangedEventHandler` as it is now? So that after the button disappears or reappears, _then_ the position is calculated and set.

Comment: You maybe could try the `LayoutUpdated` or `IsVisibleChanged` event and handle the position there; this event is part of the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fiddle around with the dispatcher priority or switch to dependency properties if you want. And doing so *might* actually result in the end result you want. But fundamentally, the real problem here is simply that you are using the wrong properties to retrieve the window's width and height.

As [the documentation explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged), the `SizeChanged` event:

> Occurs when either the **ActualHeight** or the **ActualWidth** properties change value on this element.

All you really need to do in order to fix your program is use the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties when computing the new window position, since *these* are the properties that are actually guaranteed to have changed when the event is raised.

Here is an actual minimal, complete code example that illustrates the technique:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO62961161AnchorBottomRightWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
      <p:Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="800"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="450"/>
        <p:Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Toggle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="700"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </p:Style.Triggers>
      </p:Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _toggle;

    public bool Toggle
    {
        get => _toggle;
        set
        {
            if (_toggle != value)
            {
                _toggle = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Toggle)));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle = !Toggle;
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect desktopWorkingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;

        this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.ActualWidth;
        this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.ActualHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: This technique works well! However there is a visual "flash" because the reposition happens ever so slightly after the resize that triggers it (more visually obvious for windows with more content). I would believe this is the best one can do, and that it's simply a shortcoming of WPF that despite extending window size rightward/downward being so easy and smooth, it's not supported to do it smoothly leftward/upward.